# python replace two optional strings with a third (looking for a neat way)

Tags: python

I'd like to replace two optional strings with a third, i.e. I'd like to be able to do:

```
string.replace(a or b, c)
```

Yeah yeah I can loop on a predefined list, or I can also use two `replace` commands. I'm just wondering if there's anything neater available that I'm not aware of.

**example**

I have a string like this:

```
'foo bar baz'
```

I'd like to replace 'foo' with 'yay' and also 'bar' with 'yay' to get:

```
'yay yay baz'
```

I can easily do:

```
'foo bar baz'.replace('foo', 'yay').replace('bar', 'yay')
```

But that's kinda repetitive. I'm thinking is there any neat way to do it (maybe some esoteric function from some library that extends the string functions... I dunno...)

Comment: I don't get what you want to do, an example would help.

Comment: thanks @Andy, but I don't have any problem with basic python. I can easily loop on a predefined list or dictionary. I'm just wondering if there's a neater way to do something so simple...

Comment: And I didn't even finish that sentence and got an answer. I love this site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re
re.sub("a|b", "c", str)
```

e.g.

```
re.sub("foo|bar", "yay", "foo bar baz")
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the `re` solution :

```
import re
a = "hello world"
print re.sub("hello|world", "foo", a) # "foo foo"
```

Comment: You answered at the same time as @SudeepJuvekar, and both answeres are the same. I picked his arbitrarily, and gave you a +1.

Answer (score 1):

I think regex is best here.  But here is the crappy pure-python version, for completeness sake..

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x.replace(y, 'yay'), ('foo', 'bar'), 'foo bar baz')
'yay yay baz'
```

This is not very pythonic, because of the `lambda`.  But you can remove the lambda with:

> Some esoteric function from some library that extends the string functions

and that might look something like this:

```
>>> from string import replace
>>> from functools import partial
>>> function = partial(replace, new='yay')
>>> reduce(function, ('foo', 'bar'), 'foo bar baz')
'yay yay baz'
```

The functional programming guys might like it, but most people would prefer a regex I think.

Comment: I like the second solution, just because it's so over the top. I didn't know lambda was not pythonic (I always loved it), so no problem there. but thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r'abc|def', 'xyz', 'abc def')
'xyz xyz'
```

you can use re.sub